# Error storing a return value from the Stored procedure in Execute SQL task

Tags: ssis

The Error from the execute sql task is

The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::ReturnResult" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

The SSIS package was working fine till date but suddenly it showed an error today .

The script which i wrote in execute sql task is

```
Declare @ReturnValue int
EXEC @ReturnValue =   DATABASE.dbo.StoredProcedure
Select @ReturnValue
```

The result set is configured to single row and in the resultset

```
ResultName= 0
VariableName=User::ReturnResult
```

The return value from the stored proc is either 0 or -1 ( Success or failure )
Since it is a production issue i dont have access to SP or the tables . So can this error occur due to connection issue with the Sybase server or its an issue with the Stored proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message is telling you that the stored proc is no longer returning just the 0 or -1 you are expecting (could it be returning null?)

Use a tool like sql server profiler to verify the parameters being passed into the stored proc and emulate the same steps to understand why the return type is different.

Comment: I couldn't find any SQL Profiler like tool for sybase which is for free  but i used MDA tables to monitor the queries in the data server .The below link helped me writing  MDA queries to monitor database objects activity                                                             http://sybase-addict.com/2010/05/01/sybase-sql-stored-procedures-to-use-mda-tables/